# why does get_metric_data return empty if any one dimension object is removed ? eg. "Name": "ImageId"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

```
import datetime
import boto3

# Create a CloudWatch client
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'disk_used_percent',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'CWAgent',
                    'MetricName': 'disk_used_percent',
                    "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "path",
                    "Value": "/movies"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "InstanceId",
                    "Value": "i-0b123456789"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "ImageId",
                    "Value": "ami-0b123456789"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "InstanceType",
                    "Value": "t2.micro"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "device",
                    "Value": "xvdf"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "fstype",
                    "Value": "xfs"
                }
            ]
                },
                'Period': 300,  # Adjust the period as needed (in seconds)
                'Stat': 'Average',  # Specify the statistical method you desire
            }
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),  # Adjust the time range as needed
    EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
)
print(response)
print()
metric_data = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values']
timestamps = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Timestamps']

# Printing the metric data and timestamps
for value, timestamp in zip(metric_data, timestamps):
    print(f'Timestamp: {timestamp}, Disk Used Percent: {value}')
```

in above code snippet it doesnt give the values if I remove                     {"Name": "ImageId","Value": "ami-0b123456789"} OR the InstanceType from the dimensions.

The Query editor has

SELECT AVG(disk_used_percent) FROM CWAgent WHERE path = '/movies'

[image]

```
Under the Source:-
-------------------
{
    "sparkline": true,
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "SELECT AVG(disk_used_percent) FROM CWAgent WHERE path = '/movies'", "label": "Query1", "id": "q1", "yAxis": "left" } ]
    ],
    "view": "singleValue",
    "stacked": true,
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "stat": "Average",
    "period": 300
}
```

`aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace CWAgent --metric-name disk_used_percent` gives...

```
{"Namespace": "CWAgent",
"MetricName": "disk_used_percent",
"Dimensions": [
{
"Name": "path","Value": "/movies"
},
{
"Name": "InstanceId","Value": "i-0b123456789"
},
{
"Name": "ImageId","Value": "ami-0b123456789"
},
{
"Name": "InstanceType","Value": "t2.micro"
},
{
"Name": "device","Value": "xvdf"
},
{
"Name": "fstype","Value": "xfs"
}]},
```

Comment: I had the same problem.  In my case, I wanted data for a specified `InstanceId`, but got nothing back unless I added `InstanceType`.  In my case, `InstanceId` alone wasn't an "aggregation dimension," but the pair `InstanceId, InstanceType` _was_.